# countApproxDistinctByKey in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to use `countApproxDistinctByKey` in pyspark (1.4 and 1.5) but cannot find it.

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.scala#L417

Am I missing something or has not been ported / wrapped yet?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, hasn't been ported yet. You can only do `countApproxDistinct` as of 1.5.

[Source code for python RDD](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/rdd.py)